# How can I Print text from all buttons?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to print the text of the the button,but every time my for loop runs I am not getting the next text from the button instead the text of first button is printed to the console all the time.

can anyone please help in understanding where I have made a mistake?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.example.com/example.php");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='responsive- tabs responsive-tabs--enabled']/ul/li['+ i +']")).getText());
        Thread.sleep(3000);

    }
}
```

Above is my code,if I try to print text of a buttons individually rather then taking into for loop I am able to print ,but when I take the same in a for loop I get text only from first button 4 times.

**My current output:**
Appium
Appium
Appium
Appium

**Expected output**
Appium
Selenium
API
Testing

Comment: Shouldn't `li['+ i +']` be `li["+ i +"]`?

Comment: @cruisepandey it should be li["+ i +"].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of **for loop**, you can go for **for each** loop like this :

Note that I am using `findElements` , So that I can iterate over a list.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='responsive- tabs responsive-tabs--enabled']/ul/li"))
for(WebElement ele : elements){
System.out.println(ele.getText());
}
```

Comment: can you please help me in understanding ,why using for loop is wrong?

Comment: Still you can use it , For each would give you more readability and ease for a list.No need to make XPATH dynamic by introducing `['"+i+"']`